# MySQL Import with TYPE=InnoDB

Tags: mysql, linux, sed, backup, innodb

I have a huge MySQL backup file (like 4-5 GB) with TYPE=InnoDB but the database I am gonna import in is a higher version and it does not accept ENGINE=InnoDB instead.
Is there a way so that I can replace TYPE=InnoDB by ENGINE=InnoDB by command line in Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create backup of your original SQL dump file.
2. Run

   sed -i 's/TYPE=InnoDB/ENGINE=InnoDB/g' yourfile.sql

Comment: Why inline? Just sed and pipe it to mysql. That will be one file read instead of two.

Comment: @akuzminsky you can't easily debug sed pipe if something goes wrong.